# SMS Intent Opening Inbox instead of Compose SMS

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, start-activity

I am using the following Code to create a sms for my app.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "My sms message");
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent)
```

This code seems to work perfectly fine for many mobile phones. It takes me to the compose message screen with message body already entered and user can select the recipient and click send , i tested this on my Huawei G610 running android 4.2.2 and on another HTC running android 2.3.

But every time i test it out on any Sony Device i do not get the adequate result. Instead of taking to the compose message screen it takes the user to their inbox. Clicking on Compose New Message Button opens up the compose screen with the sms body already written from the code

How can i get the app to take the user directly to the compose sms page and not to the inbox ?

Comment: That's just how Sony's SMS app is written, apparently. There's likely nothing you can do about it.

Comment: that is horrible -_-